# Problem with plotting function with pgfplots (Takagi function)

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to plot step functions that when sumed will constitute the [Takagi function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blancmange_curve). The graph of the first step functions is as it should be, but the graph of the second one fails. See the MWE below (the first one is in black, the second one in red). How to fix it?

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\tikzset{
declare function={Floor(\x)=round(\x-0.5);},
declare function={Ceil(\x)=round(\x+0.5);},
declare function={Distance(\x)=min(\x-Floor(\x),Ceil(\x)-x);},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north}
]

\addplot [
mark=none,
domain=0.0001:2,
samples=500,
smooth,
thick,black,
] {Distance(x)};
\addlegendentry{$x\mapsto \varphi(x)
  :=\min\{x-\lfloor x\rfloor,\lceil x\rceil-x\}
:=\operatorname{dist}(x,\mathbb{Z})$}

\addplot [
mark=none,
domain=0.00001:2,
samples=500,
smooth,
thick,red,
] {Distance(2*x)/2};
\addlegendentry{$x\mapsto \frac{1}{2}\varphi(2x)$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't actually have to implement `Floor` and `Ceil`, `pgfmath` already has them as `floor` and `ceil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just forgotten the backslash in the final `\x` in the definition of your `Distance` function. And as mentioned in a comment, `pgfmath` already defines `floor` and `ceil`, so you don't have to define them yourself.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\tikzset{
declare function={Distance(\x)=min(\x-floor(\x),ceil(\x)-\x);},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north}
]

\addplot [
mark=none,
domain=0.0001:2,
samples=500,
smooth,
thick,black,
] {Distance(x)};
\addlegendentry{$x\mapsto \varphi(x)
  :=\min\{x-\lfloor x\rfloor,\lceil x\rceil-x\}
:=\operatorname{dist}(x,\mathbb{Z})$}

\addplot [
mark=none,
domain=0.00001:2,
samples=500,
smooth,
thick,red,
] {Distance(2*x)/2};
\addlegendentry{$x\mapsto \frac{1}{2}\varphi(2x)$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, stupid of me...